# Latex, how to highlight code with different background colors

Tags: minted

I saw the example of minted:
[image]

I write my java code like that:

```
\begin{minted}[breaklines, breakanywhere, escapeinside=||]{java}
 private byte[] doEncryption(String data, SecretKey key){
    |\colorbox{green}{Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog"); }|
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    logger.info("plaintext is: "+data); 
    cipher.init|(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key);
    byte[] cipherText=cipher.doFinal(data);
    logger.info("ciphertext is: "+cipherText);
    return cipherText;
    }
\end{minted}
```

However, I only get  [image]

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please use a complete MWE that contains the ``\documentclass``, all the ``\usepackages`` (and libraries if you use ``tikz`` or something like that), as well as the ``\begin{document}`` and ``\end{document}``. Please refer to [this](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl) and to [this](http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)

Comment: What do you want it to look like? What's wrong with the result?

Comment: Very good question! That's indeed a surprising output!

Comment: The problem are the " signs, without them the box works

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the `"` inside the colorbox, for a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{"#1"}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines, breakanywhere, escapeinside=||]{java}
 private byte[] doEncryption(String data, SecretKey key){
    |\colorbox{green}{Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(\foo{MyLog}); }|
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    logger.info("plaintext is: "+data); 
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key);
    byte[] cipherText=cipher.doFinal(data);
    logger.info("ciphertext is: "+cipherText);
    return cipherText;
    }

\end{minted} 
\end{document}
```

[image]